# Default C# String encoding

Tags: c#, string

I am having some issues with the default string encoding in C#. I need to read strings from certain files/packets. However, these strings include characters from the 128-256 range (extended ascii), and all of these characters show up as question marks , instead of the proper character. For example, when reading a string ,it could come up as "S?meStr?n?" if the string contained the extended ascii characters.

Now, is there any way to change the default encoding for my application? I know in java you could define the default character set from command line.

Comment: The problem may be in your viewer (Webpage, WPF application, etc). How are you displaying the text? Can you post some examples, please?

Comment: I've actually found out the issue. I wasn't too familiar with C#'s encoding feature. 
I've edited my Packet/File reading classes from Encoding.ASCII to Encoding.Default, and it actually seems to be reading the strings correctly now (from the packets at least).

Comment: Don't use Encoding.Default - it can change between machines and your code will not work properly (check out http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html in addition to Jon's and Sean's answers)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no one single "extended ASCII" encoding. There are lots of different 8-bit encodings which are compatible with ASCII for the bottom 128 values.

You need to find out what encoding your files *actually* use, and specific that when reading the data with `StreamReader` (or whatever else you're using). For example, you may want encoding [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252):

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

.NET strings are *always* sequences of UTF-16 code points. You can't change that, and you shouldn't try. (That's true in Java as well, and you really *shouldn't* use the platform default encoding when calling `getBytes()` etc unless that's what you really, really mean.)

Comment: I have run up against this a few times while reading files from my European counterparts. The solution was, "please tell me how you are encoding your files" and then I can use the right encoding when reading the file. Usually, I end up putting the encoding in a config setting so that if they change we can still read in the file without a code change.

Comment: You should ask them to use UTF-8 unless they can give a good reason why they can't.

Comment: Is it not even possible to create a simple ASCII (range of 0-127 characters) string constant? I'm asking this because I took a peek in my compiled C# code with TotalCommander and I thought to my self that it would be interesting to make it to an ASCII string in it.

Comment: @AdamL.S.: It's not clear what you mean. You can declare a string constant: `const string Foo = "XYZ";` - that's fine for any string. This question is about encoding - it's not clear how your comment relates to it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: My comment relates to it in how it is stored inside the compiled *.exe file. So if I write `const string foo = "bar";` the “bar” string will appear in the binary as `b a r `, in UTF-16. (This can be checked with a hex editor or Total Commander Viewer.) However I found out, if I store it as a string resource, it will be stored as an UTF-8 string instead. Although it is completely irrelevant how it is stored, but it is an interesting thing to toy with, in my opinion.

Comment: @AdamL.S.: Okay - I'd actually expected that it would be in UTF-8, but I certainly wouldn't change any code on that front anyway.

Answer (score 2):

An [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) can be specified in at least one overload of functions for reading text - for example, [ReadAllText(string, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx).

So if you no a file's encoded using Windows-1252, then you can specify it like so:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(someFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Of course, doing this requires knowing ahead of time which code page is being used.